# An internal error occurred during: "C/C++ Indexer".java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm totally new with `cocos2d-x`.
I had problem when using `cocos2d-x-3.3rc0` in OS X 10.9

I create project by using command line :
`python cocos.py new ProjName --package .....`
It created a `ProjName` for me.
I import the `proj.android` to build and run, for the first time, every thing seem to be OK.

But the next day, when i open it, the problem occurred.

```
"An internal error occurred during: "C/C++ Indexer".java.lang.NullPointerException"
```

In `C/C++ perspective` in Eclipse, it look like a empty project (there's nothing in that project - in `Java perspective`, it does), and i can't do anything with it.
The `proj.ios_mac` still work fine.
Please help me !

Comment: need more info, specifically the code where the exception occurs. Pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.NullPointerException  ps: no images please (get scaled and become unreadable), you can just copy paste logs, call stack, code, etc as text from the ide and paste it here.

Comment: I solved it according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384264/after-import-an-cocos2d-project-eclipse-raise-an-two-weird-errors-android-lib.    
I don't actually know why, but it worked.   Thank a lot for your help @LearnCocos2D.